# Small Swing Application Crashes after Clicking Buttons multiple times

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

This code is a simple engine for a trivia game. The idea is that the answers show up on the JButtons. To do this, I had to setup a refresh method that deletes everything and repaints it. It seems that every time this method is called, it gets increasingly slow. It gets so slow after about 10 button clicks, that it will stop responding and I will have to manually shutdown the program.

Thanks

```
package mainPackage;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MainGame{
    static JFrame frame;
    static WindowComp w;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame("Game");
        w = new WindowComp();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        WindowComp.setAnswers( "start", "start", "start", "start");
        WindowComp.refreshAll(w, frame);

        WindowComp.setAnswers("final", "final", "final", "final");
        WindowComp.refreshAll(w, frame);
    }
}

public class WindowComp extends JComponent implements ActionListener {
    static JButton [] buttons = new JButton[4];
    static JLabel question = new JLabel("default");

    public WindowComp(){
        setAnswers("default", "default", "default", "default");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == buttons[0]){
            setQuestion("button 1");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttons[1]){
            setQuestion("button 2");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttons[2]){
            setQuestion("button 3");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttons[3]){
            setQuestion("button 4");
        }
        refreshAll(MainGame.w, MainGame.frame);
    }

    public void addAll(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttons[0].addActionListener(this);
        buttons[1].addActionListener(this);
        buttons[2].addActionListener(this);
        buttons[3].addActionListener(this);
        add(buttons[0]);
        add(buttons[1]);
        add(buttons[2]);
        add(buttons[3]);
        add(question);
    }

    public static void setAnswers( String ans1, String ans2, String ans3,String ans4){
        buttons[0] = new JButton("Answer 1 : " + ans1);
        buttons[1] = new JButton("Answer 2 : " + ans2);
        buttons[2] = new JButton("Answer 3 : " + ans3);
        buttons[3] = new JButton("Answer 4 : " + ans4);
    }

    public static void setQuestion(String q){
        question = new JLabel("Question: " + q);
    }

    public static void refreshAll(WindowComp w, JFrame frame){
        w.removeAll();
        w.addAll();
        w.revalidate();
        frame.add(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) it was made so you don't have to remove -> add -> revalidate yourself. Give it a try

Comment: @krzyk (hoping that you will see this) : This could have been the right answer. It may be worth mentioning here, at least: With each call to `refreshAll`, you are adding action listeners to the buttons. After a few clicks, the buttons will have dozens of action listeners. Ths could mess things up a bit. Regardless of that, the overall approach is not the best, and you should consider e.g. a `CardLayout` , as Frakcool suggested.

Comment: The number of listeners grows exponentially. I've just tried it.

Comment: *"I had to setup a refresh method that deletes everything and repaints it"* ... Your method is like not liking the color of the walls of a house, and using a nuclear bomb to destroy it, rebuild it, and repaint it, while expecting no radiation... - You could implement this much easier with a change of cards, as other commenters already indicated...You could also reuse the elements that display the question and answer-buttons, based on swapping their texts and behaviours based on separate classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, as said in the comments, you add too many ActionListeners, which results in the problem you described.

Following will be some advice that I'd like to give you.

First of all, you don't have to use the keyword `new` everytime you want to change the text of the buttons. Garbage collection will get rid of not used buttons, but why do you want new buttons instead of just updating the text on the buttons via `setTest(String)` which would not invoke any garbage collection.

Lastly, try to use the constructor more, you can actually let everything you need(atleast in this case, not generally) be created when calling the constructor. As an example, you can creat all JButtons in the constructor and add all listeners to the buttons(I'll supply some code below).

I rewrote your code a little bit, it does not have the same functionality that yours had, but it also doesn't crash.

```
package de;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainGame{
static JFrame frame;
static WindowComp w;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new JFrame("Game");
    w = new WindowComp();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.add(w);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(true);
   /*WindowComp.setAnswers( "start", "start", "start", "start");
    WindowComp.refreshAll(w, frame);

    WindowComp.setAnswers("final", "final", "final", "final");
    WindowComp.refreshAll(w, frame);*/
}

}




package de;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class WindowComp extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

static JButton [] buttons;
static JLabel question;

public WindowComp(){
    question = new JLabel("default");
    buttons = new JButton[4];
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    buttons[0] = new JButton("Answer 1 : " + "default");
    buttons[1] = new JButton("Answer 2 : " + "default");
    buttons[2] = new JButton("Answer 3 : " + "default");
    buttons[3] = new JButton("Answer 4 : " + "default");

    buttons[0].addActionListener(this);
    buttons[1].addActionListener(this);
    buttons[2].addActionListener(this);
    buttons[3].addActionListener(this);
    addAll();

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == buttons[0]){
        setQuestion("button 1");
        setAnswers( "start", "start", "start", "start");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == buttons[1]){
        setQuestion("button 2");
        setAnswers("final", "final", "final", "final"); 
    }
    if(e.getSource() == buttons[2]){
        setQuestion("button 3");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == buttons[3]){
        setQuestion("button 4");
    }
    //refreshAll(MainGame.w, MainGame.frame);

}
public void addAll(){

    add(buttons[0]);
    add(buttons[1]);
    add(buttons[2]);
    add(buttons[3]);
    add(question);

}



public static void setAnswers( String ans1, String ans2, String ans3,String ans4){
    buttons[0].setText("Answer 1 : " + ans1);
    buttons[1].setText("Answer 2 : " + ans2);
    buttons[2].setText("Answer 3 : " + ans3);
    buttons[3].setText("Answer 4 : " + ans4);

}

public static void setQuestion(String q){
    question.setText("Question: " + q);
}

public static void refreshAll(WindowComp w, JFrame frame){
    w.removeAll();
    w.addAll();
    w.revalidate();
    frame.add(w);

}
```

}

Edit: As far as current code goes, your function `refreshAll(WindowComp w, JFrame frame)` is not invoked anymore, because there currently is no need for invoking it. I commented it out with this edit after testing the program without the call.

Comment: Would I have to call repaint() ? to get the button text to change?

Comment: I tested it and no you don't have to call repaint().

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the ActionListeners are always added to the buttons but never removed. A quick fix would be to write a method to remove them:

```
public void removeActionListeners(){
        buttons[0].removeActionListener(this);
        buttons[1].removeActionListener(this);
        buttons[2].removeActionListener(this);
        buttons[3].removeActionListener(this);
}
```

And then call it in your "refreshAll()":

```
public static void refreshAll(WindowComp w, JFrame frame){
        w.removeActionListeners();
        w.removeAll();
        w.addAll();
        w.revalidate();
        frame.add(w);
}
```

...as pointed out already this is **not** the best way of doing this but it doesn't lag out anymore.